# Google Maps v3: Marker and infowindow is not displaying

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

This map that is partially working. It displays both maps BUT I can't figure out why the marker and infowindow are not showing up on the road map. Can you guys please help me?

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/btqVx/2/

**Javascript:**

```
//<![CDATA[
// ************************   Variables   ************************
//****** Map Options ******//
var roadmap =
        {
        infoWindow: new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        options:
            {
            map:
                {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng( 34.021868, -118.29322300000001 ),
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
                }
            }
        };
        roadmap.options.marker =
            {
            position: roadmap.options.center,
            title: 'Hello',
            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png',
            shadow: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/msmarker.shadow.png'
            };

//****** Street view Options ******//
var StreetView =
        {
        options:
            {
            position: roadmap.options.map.center,
            zoom: 1
            },
        geometry:
            {
            MaxDistance: 30,
            cameraHeading: 0
            }
        };
        StreetView.StreetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();


// ************************   Functions   ************************
//****** InfoWindow ******//
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        infoWindow.getContent();marker.openInfoWindowTabsHtml(infoTabs);
    });
}


//****** onLoad ******//
function googleMaps()
{
    // ************************   Road map   ************************
    roadmap.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), roadmap.options.map );


    // ************************   Road map's Marker   ************************
    roadmap.options.marker.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), roadmap.options.map );
    roadmap.marker = new google.maps.Marker( roadmap.options.marker );


    // ************************   Add infoWindow & click Listener to Marker   ************************
    bindInfoWindow( roadmap.marker, roadmap.map, roadmap.infoWindow, roadmap.options.marker.title );


    // ************************   Street view map   ************************
    var building = StreetView.options.position;

    function getHeading(buildingLatLng, callback) {
        StreetView.StreetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(buildingLatLng, StreetView.geometry.MaxDistance, function (streetViewPanoramaData, status) {
            if(status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
                var car = streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng;
                callback(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(car, building));         
            }
        });
    }

    getHeading(building, function(carHeading) {
      StreetView.map = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("map_StreetView"), {
        position: StreetView.options.position,
        pov: { heading: carHeading, pitch: 0, zoom: 1 }
      });
    });

} //end of load()


// ************************   Load   ************************
//Call googleMaps after document is loaded
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){
    googleMaps();
    //you can add more code here
    });
//]]>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Street View & Road map</title>

    <!-- START: Google Maps API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="street_view.js"></script>
    <!-- __END: Google Maps API -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map-container" >
        <div id="map_StreetView" style="width: 350px; height: 250px"></div><br/>
        <div id="map" style="width: 350px; height: 250px"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello again :) Here's my updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/RgaCe/

I made these changes:

(1) icon/shadow became `MarkerImage`s because they didn't line up

```
    var bluePin = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png',
      new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(15, 32));

    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/msmarker.shadow.png',
      new google.maps.Size(59, 32),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(15, 32));
```

(2)

```
roadmap.options.marker = 
        {
        // CHANGE add .map.
        position: roadmap.options.map.center,
```

(3) Comment this function that is not defined `//marker.openInfoWindowTabsHtml(infoTabs);`

(4)

```
// CHANGE roadmap.map TO roadmap.options.marker.map
    bindInfoWindow( roadmap.marker, roadmap.options.marker.map, 
      roadmap.infoWindow, roadmap.options.marker.title );
```

Comment: As you can see, it is the same map you help me with, with some customizations. Thanks a lot =)

Comment: @Omar I do my best :) Still, there's a minor correction you should make with the MarkerImages. I updated the answer above, the last Points in each MarkerImage should be (15,32), not (0,32). The example I was copying used a different icon and comparing to a map with default icon, I noticed they weren't matching up. The offset is about a quarter block at the initial zoom.

Comment: @liliana I found a glitch >_< , I explained it in our chatroom

Comment: @liliana streetVew map is blank when using this coords 34.0351030, -118.2821230

Comment: I was able to find an alternative answer, based on the way google maps api v2 used to do it. However, I updated the code to use api v3: http://jsfiddle.net/ZzJFb/3/ If you want to read about it, here is the reference http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/e8cb5a8c98767745/ BTW, I also modified the marker's shadow icon so you won't have to use the "hack".

Comment: here's more info http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/069c640b0e517666?pli=1

Comment: I think it is much better! No need to play with the max Distance variable.